# There is a routing problem that needs to be solved, which is interesting, but I can't realize it

Tags: javascript, react-router, router

How to realize the routing function like unsplash? When you click the details page on the home page, a pop-up window will open, and the routing information will be changed to the routing information of the details page. When the details pop-up window is closed, the routing information will be changed to the routing information of the home page. When the details pop-up window is used, if the browser refresh function is applied, the real details page will be jumped directly. Can you give a specific implementation plan.

I used the React-router-dom of the react framework and the window.history api, but it was hard to figure out a solution.

```js
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  Link,
  useNavigate,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
const ModalContext = createContext();

const Home = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { setModalOpen } = useContext(ModalContext);

  const openDetailsModal = () => {
    setModalOpen(true);
    window.history.pushState("/details", "/details", "/details");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      <Link to="/details">Open Details Modal</Link>
      <button onClick={openDetailsModal}>Open Details Modal with Button</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Details = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { setModalOpen } = useContext(ModalContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      setModalOpen(false);
    };
  }, [setModalOpen]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Details Page</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedModalOpen =
      localStorage.getItem("modalOpen") || sessionStorage.getItem("modalOpen");

    if (storedModalOpen === "true" && !modalOpen) {
      setModalOpen(true);
    }

    localStorage.removeItem("modalOpen");
    sessionStorage.removeItem("modalOpen");
  }, [modalOpen]);

  return (
    <ModalContext.Provider value={{ modalOpen, setModalOpen }}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/details" element={<Details />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </ModalContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: The website I watch is https://unsplash.dogedoge.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe try something like this:

```js
const Test = () =>{
  const handleClick = ()=>{
    const newUrl = '/new-url';
    window.history.pushState(null, '',newUrl);
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Change Url Not Page</button>
  )
}
```

This will update your URL, but will not reload nor change the page! Then you can add all the logic you need to show the popup you need Does it suits your case?
Hope this helps

Comment: However, doing so would add a route to the record, and after refreshing it would cause backward is not logical. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: I just tried it again and found that my pushState argument passed incorrectly causing it to be pushed into the history. Now the problem is solved, thank you again.